# Groovy Notebook equivalent to IPython Notebook

Tags: groovy, jupyter-notebook

I have a lot of java components that perform data processing functions that I'd like to expose in a scripting language to analysts along the same lines of IPython.

Is there something equivalent to IPython for Groovy (or other JVM based scripting language).

Thanks.

Note I am aware of Groovy Console but as far as I know it's not comparable to IPython Notebook.

Comment: [**`Groovy Console`**](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Console) and/or [**`Groovy Shell`**](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell), is what you are looking for?

Comment: @dmahapatro thanks for the response. I was looking for some of the additional stuff like in-lining text, sharing notebooks, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most recently I have identified Beaker Notebooks as a close equivalent of Groovy Notebooks to IPython Notebooks. Beaker is a 'polyglot' notebook supporting multiple scripting languages including Groovy, R, Python etc. See here http://beakernotebook.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think the closer version is the online groovy console 
https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

it is not 1:1 features, it would a be fairly trivial to provide the equivalent charting
perhaps integrated with ploty  for exta bonus points

Answer (score 1):

The offline equivalent would be http://jwork.org/ for data/scientific visualization which can be scripted in jython as well as groovy